# Is it possible to store only the n-1 characters at the end of a buffer?

Tags: c, file-io, buffer

Is it possible to store the last n-1 characters of a buffer and then append it to the beginning of the new buffer? For example, if I'm reading data from a file and storing it in a buffer of size 1000, is it possible to just have the last n-1 characters of the current buffer and bring it to the beginning of the newbuffer which is going to read the next 1000 characters. **I don't want to re-read the data** from the file. Just save few characters from the old buffer and fit it in the beginning of new buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fptr;
    int l,count=0,index;
    char name[100],word[25],buffer[1000],*pos;
    printf("\nEnter the word to be found:");
    scanf("%s",word);
    l=strlen(word);
    printf("\nEnter the file name:");
    scanf("%s",name);
    fptr=fopen(name,"r");
    if(fptr==NULL){
        printf("\nProblem with opening the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    while ((fgets(buffer, 1000, fptr)) != NULL)
    {
        index = 0;
        while ((pos = strstr(buffer + index, word)) != NULL)
        {
            index = (pos - buffer) + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("The word %s is found %d times",word,count);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217854/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-shelton-is-it-possible-to-store-only-the-n-1-ch).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - if you are counting occurence of a specific word and reading the file in small parts, you need to take care and handle situations where only the initial part of a word is at the end of the buffer.

If your current buffer contains a part of a word then you can just copy that "half" word to the start of the buffer and in the next `fread` give another pointer and another length.

Something like:

```
#define BUF_SZ 1000

char buffer[BUF_SZ];

// Full file read
fread(buffer, 1, BUF_SZ, fp);

// do some stuff
. . .

numbers_in_half_word = 3; // Just as example. In the real code you need
                          // to calculate it based on the first input

// Copy to start of buffer
memcpy(buffer, buffer + (BUF_SZ - numbers_in_half_word), numbers_in_half_word);

// Reduced file read, i.e. max 997 chars - note: ptr moved by 3, length reduced by 3
fread(buffer + numbers_in_half_word, 1, BUF_SZ - numbers_in_half_word, fp);
```

**EDIT**

OP just posted code showing that `fgets` was used. The principle is still the same:

```
int numbers_in_half_word = 0;  // No half-word the first time. So init to zero

while ((fgets(buffer + numbers_in_half_word, 1000 - numbers_in_half_word, fptr)) != NULL)
{

   // do stuff including calculation of the new numbers_in_half_word value

   if (numbers_in_half_word)
   {
       memcpy(buffer, buffer + (1000 - 1 - numbers_in_half_word), numbers_in_half_word);
   }
}
```

Notice the **-1** in the memcpy. That is needed because `fgets` uses `buffer[999]` as the zero termination.

**Special considerations**

If the half-word (aka `numbers_in_half_word`) is 500 or more then `memmove` is better than `memcpy`

If the half-word (aka `numbers_in_half_word`) is 999 the code above will go into an endless loop as there is no room for new chars from the file.

A good program should be able to handle such cases even they are unlikely in a file of words.

Comment: by number_in_half_word, you mean the number of characters of the word to be searched that matched with the string, right?

Comment: @SharonShelton Let's say you are looking for "world" and your buffer is "A lot of words ... Hello wor" The you need to copy yhe last 3 letters (i.e. "wor") to the buffer start and then do the next `fgets`